# rails joins with select returns nil as id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, ruby-on-rails-4

Why joins query returns id as null in the last even I haven't query any like id. How should I prevent that?

```
2.1.3 :038 > Foo.select('bars.comment_1, bars.comment_2, foos.rating').joins(:bars).each do |b|
2.1.3 :039 >     p b.to_json
2.1.3 :040?>   end
  Foo Load (0.3ms)  SELECT comment_1, comment_2, rating FROM `foos` INNER JOIN `bars` ON `bars`.`foo_id` = `foos`.`id`
"{\"comment_1\":\"xyz\",\"comment_2\":\"uvw\",\"rating\":\"good\",\"id\":null}"
"{\"comment_1\":\"xyz\",\"comment_2\":\"uvw\",\"rating\":\"good\",\"id\":null}"
"{\"comment_1\":\"xyz\",\"comment_2\":\"uvw\",\"rating\":\"fair\",\"id\":null}"
"{\"comment_1\":\"xyz\",\"comment_2\":\"uvw\",\"rating\":\"poor\",\"id\":null}"
"{\"comment_1\":\"xyz\",\"comment_2\":\"uvw\",\"rating\":\"good\",\"id\":null}"
```

Comment: How do you expect it it set `id` properly if you don't select `id` column?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `only` option of `to_json` method:

```
Foo.select('bars.comment_1, bars.comment_2, foos.rating').joins(:bars).each do |b|
  p b.to_json(only: [:comment_1, :comment_2, :rating])
end
```